# Can We use java client/code to call Tridion Export-Import service in Sites9?

Tags: sdl-tridion, sites-9, content-porter-2013

I am trying to find out whether java code can be used to invoke Export-Import Service?I have seen sample code of C# but not seeing using java code

Sample C# code : http://erichuiza.blogspot.com/2013/12/tridion-2013-sp1-import-export-api.html

I am not sure whether same can be called using java client .Is there any way Tridion ExportImport service can be invoked by java client?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was found..
Need a separate WSDL to use the ImportExportService namespace. The client is now created and can access the APIs.